# Inserting a series of records into a table using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I hope this is clear - I need to use T-Sql to create records in a table using a unique list taken from a different table, with one record inserted for every Year and Quarter after 2012, with another custom value (risk) appended as well.

In other words, I have a list of NAME (taken from a SELECT DISTINCT statement) that has, say, 10 values.  For each of these 10 NAMES I need to insert a row in a separate table that has:

NAME, YEAR, QUARTER, RISK 1-2  for every NAME, YEAR, QUARTER and RISK combination from a determined starting year (2012) to the current year.

So if I had these NAMEs returned from a SELECT DISTINCT statement:

BOB,
MARY

I would want this inserted into a table:

```
BOB, 2012, Q1, Risk1    
BOB, 2012, Q1, RISK2    
BOB, 2012, Q2, Risk1    
BOB, 2012, Q2, Risk2    
BOB, 2012, Q1, Risk1    
BOB, 2012, Q2, Risk2
```

... (all the way through the current year)

```
MARY, 2012, Q1, Risk1    
MARY, 2012, Q1, RISK2    
MARY, 2012, Q2, Risk1    
MARY, 2012, Q2, Risk2    
MARY, 2012, Q1, Risk1
```

....  (and on and on until the list of names is complete.)

I'm sure there's an elegant way to do this, but I just don't have the SQL chops to figure this out.

Comment: where you get the risks? or are just 1 and 2 ?

Comment: use excle to build INSERT statement.

Comment: for the sake of this question they would just be 1 and 2

Answer (score 2):

I will give you just the details because I m just in my way home.

You need a diferent select for each value and then cross join everyone.

If you dont have a table to make select you use a `CTE` to generate those values.

```
WITH names as (
   SELECT DISTINCT name 
   FROM YourTable
), years as ( 
    SELECT 2012 as year UNION ALL
    SELECT 2013 as year UNION ALL
    SELECT 2014 as year UNION ALL
    SELECT 2015 as year UNION ALL
    SELECT 2016 as year 
), quarters as (
    SELECT 'Q1' as year UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Q2' as year UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Q3' as year UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Q4' as year
), risks as (
    SELECT 'Risk1' as risk UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Risk2' as risk 
)
SELECT N.NAME, Y.year, Q.quarter, R.risk
FROM names          N
CROSS JOIN years    Y
CROSS JOIN quarters Q
CROSS JOIN risks    R
ORDER BY N.NAME, Y.year, Q.quarter, R.risk
```

**EDIT**

For the year list you may want use a recursive CTE something more generic like this

```
with yearlist as 
(
    select 2004 as year
    union all
    select yl.year + 1 as year
    from yearlist yl
    where yl.year + 1 <= YEAR(GetDate())
)    
select year 
from yearlist 
order by year desc;
```

Comment: Upvoted. However, you might want to use `UNION ALL` to improve performance.

Comment: @FelixPamittan Told you write that in a hurry :). Now I fix it even include a better way to generate the year list.